# Separating Multi-select column values into individual columns using calculated columns

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, calculated-column

I have a Multi-Select column labeled Email that allows users to select multiple email addresses populated from an external Sharepoint list. I then get their choices and update a single-text column with their choices, commas delimited. This is what that column contains for example:

```
test@gmail,test@yahoo.com,test@aol.com,test2@gmail.com
```

What is the best method to separate each email without the colon into different columns? I have tried looking into different functions using Calculated Columns, but I'm not sure how to handle more than two email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a workflow to split the values.

The workflow will only need one action and can be written as a 2010 or 2013 style workflow. Add a Set Field in Current Item action and select the data from the Choice column using “Choices, Comma Delimited”.

[image]

The "Lunch Choices" column and the "Lunch to Order" column below look the same, but the first is a Choice column and the second is a Single Line of Text column.

[image]

(I know the example does not have email addresses... :-)  I stole the screen captures from my SharePoint Calculated Columns book.)